# Do police really care about drug dealers?

Tags: drugs, police

If we are to believe the statistics, a lot of young people take drugs or have "experimented in college" with or without inhaling.

Now some of these people will end up in the police force tasked with tracking down and jailing drug dealers.

Are we to believe that these policemen and women really care about tackling drug dealers?

Or do they just see it as a job and put all personal feelings aside.

I'm sure a fair proportion of police officers do take the occasional recreational drug. But in which case they would be getting the drugs off the very people they, in their work-life, would have to arrest.

This has always confused me.

Comment: I'm sure some of them probably do care, and see drug use as a problem that they happen to be uniquely situated to do something about. You are right that some of them may look at certain types of use as not really a problem for law enforcement, but as such it is really an _opinion_ within some law enforcement circles that you're asking about and not really a question about policy.

Comment: Are you confused that police commit *any* crime, or just drug related crime?

Comment: Most (all?) police units in the US have mandatory drug testing. That, of course, doesn't mean cops don't take drugs, but in terms of policy, it's typically stated that they should not. But that seems like an entirely separate issue than whether the police personally 'care' about drug dealers. As it is, this question is just asking for an opinion based answer.

Comment: Police may use drugs themselves (or exceed the speed limit, commit rapes & murders, &c) while still being perfectly willing to arrest drug dealers, or steal from them, e.g. https://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-44402948  For many, it's simply the ability to boss people around that attracts them to the job, not the particular laws that allow them to do so.

Comment: @jamesqf That makes sense. I mean it's like best of both worlds. Get loads of drugs for yourself while preventing anyone else form having any. Wow. Some people are a piece of work!

Answer (score 3):

Most members of the police department do not arrest drug dealers most of the time.  Police have departments just for drug enforcement and similar crimes (often called [vice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vice#Vice_squad) in the United States).  Individual officers may be responding to calls, walking a beat, or investigating murders or thefts as well.

Beyond that, most departments do take an extra effort to hire police officers who do not regularly use drugs.

[Eastern Kentucky University](https://plsonline.eku.edu/insidelook/can-you-become-police-officer-history-drug-use) suggests that police departments use background checks and polygraphs to weed out many of those who have used drugs.  Some police departments may even have [drug testing](https://blogs.findlaw.com/blotter/2016/08/are-cops-drug-tested.html).  They are especially concerned about recent drug use.

Comment: Yes, I guess if you try and get a job in the drug squad you are probably against drugs unless you are very career minded.

Comment: @zooby not necessarily. A job is a job and not everyone is able to match their employment with their personal morals. Note that a lot of police efforts against drug syndicates are really more after the violence that accompanies them.

Comment: @blip: I have to disagree.  Police efforts against drug syndicates &c are about getting more funding for larger police departments.  If drugs were not illegal, there would be no drug syndicates.  Reflect on Prohibition, and the idea that those who refuse to learn from history are condemned to repeat it :-(